419 page error with Laravel, InteriaJS and Laravel
I have been going through all the questions and answers that I can find concerning this issue but I am getting nowhere.
I am using reactjs and inertiajs with laravel and I can't fix what I am assuming is the csrf issue.  I keep getting 419 Page Expired when I try to submit log in credentials on a login page.
setup
laravel v10.4,
inertiajs v1.0,
reactjs v18.2
Login.tsx (edited for brevity)
    const form = useForm({
        email:    '',
        password: '',
    });
    
    function login(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        form.post(route('login'), {
        onFinish: () => {
                form.reset('password');
            },
        });
    }


...return (
    <div>
        <!-- name input div -->
        <!-- password input div -->
        <Button onClick={login}> Log in </Button>
    </div>
)

The session driver was initially set to database but I have set it to file
.env
SESSION_DRIVER=file

Firstly I was hoping that it would work out of the box since the docs state

Laravel automatically includes the proper CSRF token when making requests via Inertia or Axios. However, if you're using Laravel, be
sure to omit the csrf-token meta tag from your project, as this will
prevent the CSRF token from refreshing properly.

but I had no joy. Is there more to this?
I have tried:

removing StartSession, ShareErrorsFromSesssion from $middlewareGroups in Kernel.php
adding <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"> to my app.blade.php, and then adding <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" /> into the form JSX
adding csrf_token manually in form

    const token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');

    const form = useForm({
        email:    '',
        password: '',
        _token:   token,
    });

Nothing is working and I still get the 419 error. Are there any other options I can try?

SESSSION_DRIVER=file should be SESSION_DRIVER Your .env has 3 (S) inside. Another is try to use database instead of file (if you have the migration files migrated to your database)

csrf is already handled by inertia if you are using useForm

@Mr.Kenneth I don't think you even read my post... :(

so you fixed your typo?

@Mr.Kenneth I sure did, but that does not change the fact you literally stated that I should either try things that have already been tried or that you gave me information I literally quoted. Perhaps, you scanned my post saw a typo in a highlighted section and decided not to read the rest?

No its just this was the same issue that I had when I did encounter my 419 errors before.
